# Reset repo in Bitbucket to empty state

Tags: git, configuration, repository, bitbucket, reset

is there any way (plugin, api feature, ...) to reset a repository in Atlassian Bitbucket to its "empty" state?

I found a lot of tutorials on how to reset a git repo to it's initial commit, but what I need is a empty repo like if I would have created a fresh one on Bitbucket. So it's not really a git related question but rather Bitbucket-specific.

I could delete the repo and re-create it with the same name, but then all my settings are lost (like Jenkins hooks). That's what I would like to avoid.

I'm working with Bitbucket v4.4.1.

Background: I'm doing trainings on software development and I have to reset the tools before each training. This is a bit annoying and time-consuming. A big reset button would save me a lot of time :-P

I'm open to any suggestion that makes my life more enjoyable ;-)

Thanks in advance,

Fred

Comment: Maybe try remove all the unneeded files locally (physical files via explorer), then from cmd doing `git init` and `git push -f`

Comment: Bitbucket is a host for Git or Mercurial based repositories. Is your issue that you are using Mercurial, rather than Git?

Comment: @JSTL: Definitely not

Answer (score 0):

I think you're effectively asking how to delete all branches on Bitbucket, which appears to be forbidden. I tried [deleting my `master` branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syLIN.png) on a test repo via

```
git push --delete origin master
```

and received the following error message:

```
remote: error: refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/master
To bitbucket.org:user/test.git
 ! [remote rejected] master (deletion of the current branch prohibited)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:user/test.git'
```

Even `--force` wasn't able to convince Bitbucket to let me do this.

The web interface similarly won't let me delete my `master` branch:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to tag the first commit as "INITIAL" and doing a hard reset to that commit. Still have to delete branches, but it saves some time.